# Как заменить ряды в таблице >3

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, dom

Делаю поиск AJAX'ом по нескольким параметрам, где данные будут подгружаться в таблицу. Таблица выглядит так:

```
name | surname | age
-----+---------+-----
____ | _____   | ___
-----+---------+-----
Petya|Ivanov   |15
John |Smith    |22
```

Здесь первая строка - название колонок, вторая поля ввода, 3-я и далее это результаты поиска.

Пытался сделать так:

```
$("#search input").live("keyup",function(){

    var tr_td = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    var tr1 = tr_td.rows[0].innerHTML;
    var tr2 = tr_td.rows[1].innerHTML;

    var result = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Search.php",
                data: data,
                async: false
            }).responseText; 

    var trs = "<tr>" + tr1 + "</tr><tr>" + tr2 + "</tr>" + result;
    tr_td.innerHTML = trs;      
});
```

,но ввести данные не получается. Как можно это сделать, чтобы менялась только нижняя часть таблицы(3-й и далее ряды), а не производилась полная замена?

**UPD:**

Данные с сервера приходят вида:

```
<tr><td>Petya</td><td>Ivanov</td><td>15</td></tr>
...
<tr>         Другие тикие же строки         </tr>
```

Изначально была таблица как сверху, только первые две строки. Если делать DOM'ом, то мне кажется придется делать цикл для каждой пары , пришедшей с сервера..

Comment: Можете привести код начальной таблицы и сказать что в неё добавить? тогда я напишу правильный код...

Comment: Ну что @alex_90 сработало?

Comment: Ура!! Получилось!! Спасибо, @Rules. Только у вас там заместо children child написано было.. А так все работает. Ну, еще один подводный камень - whitespace'ы, но это наверное на сервере лучше предотвращать..

Comment: А! Перепутал бывает когда JS в в голове с C++ PHP и экзаменом по физике перемешиваются :) а удалить пробелы можно и у клиента счас напишу как...

Comment: Всё написал...Удалять пробелы так:

      var reg = /(\s)+/gi;
      result = result.replace(reg,"");

Comment: Кстати, вот еще исправьте: `var child=tbody.children[2];`. А то долго не могли понять почему не так удаляет :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня была проблема с таблицами, оказалось IE таблицы вобще "константы" и без DOM не обойтись к тому же в других браузерах много багов с ними! Вобщем попробуйте так:

***UPD:***

Сделайте в таблице 
   <tbody>а сдесь тэги которые были вложены просто в table</tbody>

Вот полный код:

```
$("#search input").live("keyup", modify);
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
function modify() {
    for (var i = 2; i < tbody.child.length; i++) {
        var child = tbody.children[i];
        tbody.removeChild(child);
    }
    var result = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Search.php",
        data: data,
        async: false
    }).responseText;
    var reg = /(\s)+/gi;
    result = result.replace(reg,"");
    tbody.innerHTML += result;
}
```

***P.S.***
Допсал как удалить пробелы и исправил ошибки...

Comment: @Rules, посмотрел ваш вариант.. DOM несомненно лучше чем обычные строки. Но все же у вас есть: [недочет][1] +к этому желательно чтобы на результат был на 3 и далее строчке...

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/pfNob.jpg

Comment: @Rules, я обновил вопрос. Вы бы мне очень помогли, если бы составили цикл с учетом whitespace'ов, которые могут прийти с сервера..

Comment: ОК счас подумаю отходил на 3 часа вернулся...

Comment: Слушайте, @Rules, мне кажется DOM'ом намного сложнее это будет сделать. На мой взгляд проще будет обычным append()'ом. Единственное узкое место - это удалить старые ряды начиная с 3-го до конца. Пока думаю над этим.

Comment: Вот написал upd